# React MUI Autocomplete - Is it possible to add independent option at the rendered option list?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

At the end of the list, it should be visible option `Other` which should be static (manually added) option.

The idea is to add it manually to the DOM and should be independent from all other dynamically created list elements.

My question, is that possible and if so, how ?

When user click on that option, additional form input should appear, but that logic is already implemented, I just need to trigger click handler and use
`setFieldValue('pension_fund_name', CommonDropdownItems.Other)`

```
import { createElement, HTMLAttributes } from 'react'
import { Divider } from '@eframe-ui/react'
import { FilterDropdownProps, DropdownOptionProps } from './types'
import { Translate } from '../translate'
import { Autocomplete, Paper } from '@mui/material'
import { FilterDropdownInput } from './Input'

export const FilterDropdown = ({
  data,
  dropdownDataLayout,
  selectFieldLabel,
  fieldValue,
  errors,
  setFieldValue,
}: FilterDropdownProps) => {
  /* eslint-disable @typescript-eslint/no-explicit-any */
  const CustomPaper = (props: any) => (
    <Paper {...props} sx={{ background: '#f4f7fa', marginTop: '4px' }} />
  )

  return (
    <Autocomplete
      freeSolo
      className="gap-y-1 flex flex-col"
      options={data}
      getOptionLabel={(option: string | DropdownOptionProps) =>
        (option as { value: string }).value
      } // filter value
      onChange={(e, value) => setFieldValue(fieldValue, value)}
      renderInput={(params) => (
        <FilterDropdownInput
          error={errors}
          params={params}
          label={selectFieldLabel}
        />
      )}
      renderOption={(
        props: HTMLAttributes<HTMLLIElement>,
        option: DropdownOptionProps,
        state
      ) => {
        const { label, mixin } = option

        return (
          <>
            <li {...props} className="w-full cursor-pointer">
              {dropdownDataLayout
                ? createElement(
                    dropdownDataLayout,
                    mixin as Record<string, string>,
                  )
                : label && (
                    <>
                      <Translate label={label} />
                      <Divider className="!my-2" />
                    </>
                  )}
            </li>
          </>
        )
      }}
      PaperComponent={CustomPaper}
    />
  )
}
```

Dynamic options are rendered through this layout

```
 const TransferAssetsLayout = (option: Record<string, string>) => (
    <>
      <p className="text-text-primary typo-regular-300 px-2 pt-1">
        {option.name}
      </p>
      {option.recipient && (
        <p
          className={clsx(
            classes.italic,
            'text-text-secondary typo-regular-200 px-2 pb-1',
          )}
        >
          {option.recipient}
        </p>
      )}
      <p
        className={clsx(
          classes.italic,
          'text-text-secondary typo-regular-200 px-2 pb-1',
        )}
      >
        {`${option.address}, ${option.zip_code} ${option.location}`}
      </p>
      <Divider className="!m-0" />
    </>
  )
```

Comment: Maybe this https://mui.com/material-ui/react-autocomplete/#creatable is what you are looking for. Hope it helps.

Comment: @assembler, Thank you for your answer, I didn't know about this option. I think it could be useful, I'll try it

Comment: @assembler, FYI, your suggestion helps me a lot. Thank you

Comment: Good! I'm glad to be helpful.